# Website updating on some devices but not others

Tags: html, css

My website only works on my laptop and phone! On my ipad, (it is a school ipad, managed by the district) the website doesn't update. I have cleared the cache. I need to present this next monday (my classmates will also be using their school ipads) and it was working fine earlier. PLEASE HELP

www.andescloudforestnmea.com/next.html

EDIT: The website was updating fine before today

Replying to the comments:
Yes, i tried incognito mode but it made no difference.
Yes, what you see is right but on my school ipad i think that it my school is blocking my server or something. Is that possible?

Comment: it seems to be working fine from over here. This is what I see in the source: https://pastebin.com/UFBGyc0e ... what are you expecting to see?

Comment: Define "website doesn't update." Does it load at all? Are there any error messages?

Comment: So i was going through and changing the background to a higher resolution. On my phone and laptop, the background picture (and code that i changed) updated. On my school ipad, the old background still shows.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have already determined that your web site has been updated correctly and the files are OK on the server, it's been narrowed down to possibly your school ipad blocking your server. You can try accessing it through a web based proxy for a quick test. Try this service:

https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy

Something else you can try is to upload your web page to another server. Since it's just one page, you don't need anything special. In fact, you could save the file on any free hosting service. Here is an example I created on HTML Pasta:

https://33d08f2c-9365-4692-bc3c-3ed68c454c41.htmlpasta.com

You can create your own at https://htmlpasta.com

EDIT: P.S. Your school ipad is probably not blocking anything but has some kind of cache that you have not cleared. Since you mentioned that you cleared the browser cache already, it may be routing your network through a school proxy or something which is caching the old site on the network level (or some other type of cache)

Comment: My school blacked the first website... :( The second website would work, but the problem is that since i cant update my website (my website is a choose your own adventure game), i cant redirect to the server

Comment: You can try another proxy service as well, but I think the second option is your best bet if there is an issue with the current server you are using and your school network blocking or caching it.

Comment: Why don't you contact the school and ask them if there is a caching issue over their network? It's unlikely that it is blocked since you access it before as you said and the old version is still showing up. Alternatively, try getting a free hosting server (but you may still run into caching issues if there is a problem like that going on)

Comment: Yeah... I think I'll just ask the tech guy at our school... I'm not doing anything wrong so i wont lose points on my project beause its not my fault something is going wrong

Comment: It's probably one of the reasons I mentioned. One more thing you could try is to install a different browser on your school ipad. If there is a bug clearing the cache on the existing browser, it should work on the new browser.

Comment: Yeah i tried Google, but that results in the same, not working webpage, and the school has blocked all but a few apps.

Comment: Yes, in that case it's likely a caching issue with the school network that the ipad is connecting to. Does it have it's own data (e.g. 4G, LTE)  connection? You could try using your home WiFi instead in that case and disable the 4G. Although that would not be a real solution, you can determine the cause is the school data. Otherwise, your browser may be configured with some kind of proxy as I said before. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Figured it out! My school was blocking the reddit picture in the background and just defaulting to the last (unupdated) site.

Comment: Ah! glad you got it figured out :)